# .htaccess and json file interaction

Tags: php, json, apache, .htaccess

I have this strip of code from my .htaccess file

```
<files CONFIG.json>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</files>

<files DATA.json>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</files>
```

When I type localhost/foldername/CONFIG.json , it will display 403 Forbidden.
But when I type localhost/foldername/DATA.json , it will display the contents of DATA.json. How can I also hide my DATA.json file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FilesMatch` block like this:

```bash
<FilesMatch "(CONFIG|DATA)\.json$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</FilesMatch>
```

If you are using Apache 2.4, then use the following instead:

```bash
<FilesMatch "(CONFIG|DATA)\.json$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

> **Note:** I am only including this so others have easy reference.

Alternatively, you may use `mod_rewrite`:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(CONFIG|DATA).json$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Note that the `RewriteCond` here is optional, and ensures that the file exists first. You may remove it, if you like.